# Cannot convert a dictionary into list of tuples and sort it

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, tuples

I want to find outliers keys (names) in my dataset, so that I am trying to create a list of tuples from my dictionary and sort them by salary. That is my code

```
for key, value in data_dict.iteritems():
    sorted_dict_list = []
    sorted_dict_list.append((key, value["salary"], value["bonus"]))
    sorted_dict_list.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])
    for tuple in sorted_dict_list:
        print tuple
```

The problem is that the printed output is unsorted. What might be the problem?

Comment: can you show your data_dict ?

Comment: Why are you using a for-loop here??? Think about what you code is doing, step through it in your head... Note, **every iteration** you set `sorted_dict_list` to `[]`, so it will only ever have a single item in it when you try to sort it and loop over it.... In any case, you should provide a [mcve]

Comment: why you are sorting sorted_dict_list on every iteration? you can put that line of code outside the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare `sorted_dict_list` outside the first `for` loop, otherwise each time you go through the loop you have a new empty list. On top of that, your loop through `sorted_dict_list` is inside the first `for` loop.

So each time you loop through the outer loop you create an empty list, add the next key-value pair into it, run through the list (which is only one item long) and print out the values. Basically you are just printing out each key-value pair as you go through.

You need to move the list declaration outside the loop and un-indent the second loop.

```
sorted_dict_list = []
for key, value in data_dict.iteritems():
    sorted_dict_list.append((key, value["salary"], value["bonus"]))
    sorted_dict_list.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])

for tuple in sorted_dict_list:
    print tuple
```

This might be a better solution:

```
def sortKey(item):
    return item[1]

sorted_dict = [(key, value['salary'], value['bonus']) for key, value in data_dict.items()]
sorted_dict = sorted(sorted_dict, key=sortKey)

for item in sorted_dict:
    print(item)
```

Comment: in first solution why you are sorting sorted_dict_list on every iteration? you can put that line of code outside the for loop

Comment: I was just showing him how to update his current code to work correctly. My second solution does what you say and would be more Pythonic.

Comment: I agree, it was just hint :)

Comment: Thank you, that helped!